# Why does call to Win32::Exe's get_version_info("MyExe.exe") return the wrong FileVersion information?

Tags: perl, versioninfo

I'm migrating a bit of Perl script from an ActiveState Perl version to Strawberry Perl.  I am having trouble migrating a piece of code that retrieves the file versioning information (contained as metadata) from an executable program.

The following Strawberry Perl code retrieves product version information on the executable file.  Why doesn't the Product Version retrieved match the product version as shown when I right-click Properties | Details from Windows explorer (Product Version via right-click is: 25.4.0.0428.001).

[image]

Powershell returns the expected value (i.e. ProductVersion is extended information in VersionInfo).

```
((Get-ItemProperty "e:\\BfsCfgSvc.exe").VersionInfo.ProductVersion)
```

OUTPUT:

```
25.12.0.0817.102
```

How can I retrieve the correct product version using Strawberry Perl?

```perl
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
use Win32::Exe   qw( );

my $exe = Win32::Exe->new('e:\\BFSCfgSvc.exe');
my $version_info = $exe->get_version_info();

{
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq  = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;
print(Dumper($version_info));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```perl
$VAR1 = {
"CompanyName" => "xxxxxxx, Inc.",
"InternalName" => "BFSCfgSvc",
"ProductVersion" => "25.0.0.0",          #<-------------------------------------
"FileDescription" => "xxxxxx ",
"OriginalFilename" => "BFSCfgSvc.CONEXE",
"FileVersion" => "25.0.0.0",
"ProductName" => "xxxxxxxxx ",
"LegalTrademarks" => "xxxxxxxx",
"LegalCopyright" => "xxxxxxx"
};
```

ActiveState Perl has a Win32::File::Versioninfo module that allows access to the correct version information as shown in the following code snippet:

```perl
$DEBUG = 1;
use Win32::File::VersionInfo;


   my $FileVersionInfo = GetFileVersionInfo ("e:\\BFSCfgSvc.exe");
   if ( $FileVersionInfo ) {
      my $lang = ( ( keys %{$FileVersionInfo->{Lang}} )[0] );
      if ($lang) {
         $FileVersion = $FileVersionInfo->{Lang}{$lang}{ProductVersion};
         print "FileVersion: $FileVersion", "\n" if $DEBUG;
      }
   }
```

OUTPUT:

```
FileVersion: 25.4.0.0428.001
```

Comment: You say PS returns the correct result, and you say Win32::File::Versioninfo returns the correct result, but you said they returned different things. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: If Win32::File::VersionInfo provides the correct result, why don't you use Win32::File::VersionInfo?

Comment: PS and VersionInfo return the same and correct results.  Win32::File::VersionInfo is not a part of the Strawberry distribution (at least I don't think so).  It comes with the licensed ActiveState distribution.  I need to use the Strawberry distro (for licensing constraints), and Strawberry Perl does not include VersionInfo module.  I am looking for a workaround to get the same results in Strawberry Perl.

Comment: Re "*PS and VersionInfo return the same and correct results.*", Again, you said they returned different results. So please fix your question (one way or another).

Comment: Re "*Win32::File::VersionInfo is not a part of the Strawberry distribution*", So? Install it!

Comment: Apologies if this is not clear.
There are three discretely different methods demonstrated above that I am attempting to retrieve the file/product version information:

Comment: There are three discretely different methods demonstrated above in attempting to retrieve the product version information:
1) ActiveState Perl includes the module called  Win32::File::VersionInfo;  Using this module, I am able to correctly obtain the ProductVersion for the supplied executable file;
2) Powershell:  Using the one-liner shown above, (Get-ItemProperty......) I also get the correct ProductVersion info;
3) Strawberry Perl does NOT have the VersionInfo module.  The only workaround I found in searching returns a ProductVersion identical to the FileVersion, which is wrong.

Comment: I am unaware that I can create a custom Strawberry Perl distribution that would contain the VersionInfo module.  I'll search for ways to perform this build process.  Thanks for the "hint", ikegami.

Comment: We're not talking about creating a custom Strawberry Perl distribution We're talking about using and thus installing a Perl module. `cpan Module::Name` is how you install modules.

Answer (score 2):

[Win32::File::VersionInfo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::File::VersionInfo) is a CPAN module. ActiveState's Perl happens to include more modules beyond the standard library, but that doesn't mean that you are limited to ActiveState to use them.

You should be able to install the module:

```
$ cpan Win32::File::VersionInfo
```

After that, your program works just fine for me when I test executables that I have.

Comment: Thank you all.  Never having had to perform a Perl installation, I didn't realize that Perl distributions were inherently customizable.  I was under the impression (wrongly so) that the distribution was an all-or-nothing installation.  I learned something today!